# 'CheckPointer' - parameter passed as reference, variable expected

Tags: mql5

I'm coding an expert advisor on meta trader 5.
I coded a dll in C# with a function I imported to my mql5 file.
Here's the code:

```
#import "C:\Program Files\MetaTrader 5\MQL5\Experts\Advisors\bin\Debug\Analytical.dll"
bool Interphase(int argc, string &args[]);
#import
```

And here's the function call:

```
if (Interphase(3, CheckPointer(GetPointer(signal)))==true)
   {
     // Do stuff...
   }
```

when I try to compile it, I get the error message:

```
'CheckPointer' - parameter passed as reference, variable expected
```

I'm new to MQL5 so I'm guessing the data types don't match.
Any assistance will be appreciated.
Thanks.